# Required library libflowmanager not found

Tags: 14.04, 12.04

while compiling ubuntu doesn't found libflowmanager library.please provide the apt command for **libflowmanager** library.

**Error: configure: error: Required library libflowmanager not found; use LDFLAGS to specify library location**

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK libflowmanager is not available from any of the standard Ubuntu repositories. The [instructions for installing libprotoident](https://github.com/wanduow/libprotoident) note that

> ```
> libflowmanager    
>         * optional, but required to build the tools
>         * available from http://research.wand.net.nz/software/libflowmanager.php
> ```

If you don't need the tools, then you can configure using

```
./configure --with-tools=NO
```

which will skip the check for libflowmanager.

Comment: Thank you for your help.It works. your quick response is appreciable.